# Sending Encrypted and signed E-Mails in Delphi using Indy

Tags: delphi, encryption, indy, email

I would like to encrypt and sign an e-mail before sending. I looked into the Indy component help/demo and it looks like Indy does not support encryption of emails.

Does Indy support sending encrypted and signed emails? If so, how can I do it?

Otherwise, is there another Delphi components/library that does?

Comment: No idea about the signing part, but Indy can perfectly send encrypted mails, you do it through OpenSSL. Google for TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL code samples.

Comment: @MarcGuillot that encrypts only the socket connection between Indy and the email server. It does not encrypt the email itself. Emails can be encrypted separately, such as with PGP or S/MIME

Comment: @MarcGuillot, I explored that option but found exactly what Remy commented.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, Indy does not natively support encryption and signing of emails.

Encryption is possible with some manual work, using 3rd party libraries for PGP, etc.

Signing is more difficult, due to the dynamic way that Indy formats emails while sending them. Signing involves taking samples of email fields and data before sending, and what is in memory is not necessarily what goes over the wire, which makes it hard to sign, but not impossible.

Indy can, however, natively encrypt the socket connection to the email server, but the email itself will still be plain-text unless encrypted by the receiver or an intermediary gateway.

There are indeed 3rd party solutions to sending secure email. For instance:

[Send Email with Digital Signature in Delphi - S/MIME](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/delphi.aspx?cat=9)

[StreamSec](http://www.streamsec.com)
(which can use S/MIME on top of Indy)

Answer (score 0):

```
I found this (I think) on the Embarcadero website, so it's published and not 
secure.  However, it works elegantly to encrypt the subject.  This does not work 
on the body. I'm working a solution for that.

Endecrypt({5508BD43-3B8A-44CD-BCD2-99DED0A0218C}{7C5916C6-CC65-4F20-9DF7- 
4019D9E6306D}
...becomes...
 ﾄￊￊￏￇﾽﾻￋￌￒￌﾽￇﾾￒￋￋﾼﾻￒﾽﾼﾻￍￒￆￆﾻﾺﾻￏﾾￏￍￎￇﾼﾂﾄ￈ﾼￊￆￎ￉ﾼ￉ￒﾼﾼ￉ￊￒￋﾹￍￏￒￆﾻﾹ￈ￒￋￏￎￆﾻￆﾺ￉ￌￏ￉ﾻﾂ

To "un" crypt, simply make the encrypted text the passed value.

function TForm1.EnDeCrypt(const Value : String) : String;
var CharIndex : integer;
begin
  Result := Value;
  for CharIndex := 1 to Length(Value) do
    Result[CharIndex] := chr(not(ord(Value[CharIndex])));
end;

 just me Sam
```